# How can I edit a created control from another function?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

If I have the following code:

```
Button[] _buttonarray = new Button[40]; // it is outside any function (situated in the public partial class MainWindow : Window)
```

And a new created button in a function called

```
private void createbutton()
{

    _buttonarray[b]=new Button();

    _buttonarray[b].Content = "Content";

    ...
}
```

How Can I edit `_buttonarray[b]` content from another function like,

```
private void editbutton()
{
    _buttonarray[b].Content = "New Content";
}
```

**Note:** variable b is outside so it can be change from any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make it Static:**

`public static Button[] ButtonArray = new ..`

and use `MainWindow.ButtonArray` to access it.

Worth pointing out that by doing that, it is **shared throughout every instance of your MainWindow**.

**Edit:**

Just to point out - rather than saying 'outside' it is more common to use the definition of **Scope** , simply put - if you can access something A from somewhere B,then A is in B's Scope.

Also - read more regarding static here: [Static and instance fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645751%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

If you want to edit a specifically created button, you can keep that button in a designated field, which is in both the creation code's scope and the alteration code's scope:

```
var myButton = new Button(){Content="Content"};
_buttonarray[b]=myButton;

SomethingInCommon.SpecificButton = myButton;
```

and the access it elsewhere that have access to `SomethingInCommon`.

Keep `SpecificButton` value until you don't need it any longer.

Comment: Thanks. You answer helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're editing a button with the code you have, it's just that it's probably not the one you're expecting because the index of b has likely been iterated. Just access the right index, possibly by using Find and a predicate on Content to make sure you're editing the right button.

Comment: Could you explain how can I use the Find function to do that ?